# c# bind morris.js with datatable code not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, morris.js

I have a code to bind morris.js bar chart to datatable but it's not working.. the graph doesn't display. It souhld be like this : I have a textbox to make research by keywords. The graph should show how many time the keyword appears in the datatable depending on the date so : abscissa = date and ordinate = number of times keyword appears.

what I want to display :

[bar chart graph](http://images.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-gANNjrjphxw%2FUvvXDXB5gLI%2FAAAAAAAAAyI%2FJ2Rrloky2Bo%2Fs1600%2Fbar-01.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.d3noob.org%2F2014%2F02%2Fmaking-bar-chart-in-d3js.html&h=271&w=576&tbnid=dgUzRfy8vSoF1M%3A&docid=mqMS6ggfHAGdVM&ei=QoyMV5XtDseBaeLsr6AP&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=337&page=1&start=0&ndsp=35&ved=0ahUKEwiVlre5xfzNAhXHQBoKHWL2C_QQMwggKAEwAQ&bih=955&biw=1920)

So here is my code not working(im using ajax with webmethod) :

js code :

```
<script src="morris.js"></script>
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var word = "{'word':'" + $("#tbSearch").val() + "'}";
        Morris.Bar
            ({
            element: 'bar-chart',
            data: $.parseJSON(Graph()) + word,
            xkey: 'value',
            ykeys: ['value'],
            labels: ["nombre d'occurence"],
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
            hideHover: 'auto',
            behaveLikeLine: true,
            resize: true,
            pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
            pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
            lineColors: ['yellow', 'pink'],
            resize: true

        });
    });

    function Graph() {
        var data = "";


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'WelcomDigitalHelpDesk.aspx/GetBarchartData',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            success: function (result) {

                data = result.d;

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

        return data;
    }
</script>
```

c# code :

public class GraphData
        {
            public string label { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
        }

```
    public class GraphDataList
    {
        public List<GraphData> ListOfGraphData { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetBarchartData(string word)
    {

        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT DateDescription, COUNT(DescriptionDemande) FROM cfao_DigiHelp_index.DigiHelpData WHERE DescriptionDemande like '" + word + "' GROUP BY DateDescription";

        DataTable DTGraph = DataBaseCacheDigitalHepDeskConnection.SqlDataTable(sqlQuery, "DIGIHELP_DB");

        List<GraphData> dataList = new List<GraphData>();

        foreach (DataRow dtrow in DTGraph.Rows)
        {
            GraphData graphData = new GraphData();
            graphData.label = Convert.ToString(dtrow["DateDescription"].ToString());
            graphData.label = Convert.ToString(dtrow["DescriptionDemande"].ToString());

            dataList.Add(graphData);
        }

        //oper = null which means its first load.
        var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string data = jsonSerializer.Serialize(dataList);
        return data;

    }
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it worked so here is the answer working for me :

code js :

```
function buildChartGraph(data) {
    $('#bar-chart').html('');

    Morris.Bar
        ({
            element: 'bar-chart',
            data: JSON.parse(data),
            xkey: 'label',
            ykeys: ['value'],
            labels: ['value'],
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
            hideHover: 'auto',
            behaveLikeLine: true,
            resize: true,
            pointFillColors: ['blue'],
            pointStrokeColors: ['darkblue'],
            lineColors: ['skyblue', 'orange'],
            resize: true

        });
}

function GetOccurence() {
    var data = "";


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        url: "WelcomDigitalHelpDesk.aspx/GetBarchartData",

        data: "{'word':'" + $("#tbSearch").val() + "'}",

        dataType: "json",

        success: function (result) {

            buildChartGraph(result.d);

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Code c# :

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetBarchartData(string word)
    {

    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT TOP 40 DateDescription, COUNT(DescriptionDemande) FROM TableName WHERE DescriptionDemande like '%" + word + "%' GROUP BY DateDescription";

    DataTable DTGraph = DataBaseCacheDigitalHepDeskConnection.SqlDataTable(sqlQuery, "DbName");

    List<GraphData> dataList = new List<GraphData>();

    foreach (DataRow dtrow in DTGraph.Rows)
    {
        GraphData graphData = new GraphData();

        graphData.value = Convert.ToString(dtrow[1].ToString());
        graphData.label = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Parse( dtrow[0].ToString()).ToShortDateString());

        dataList.Add(graphData);
    }


    var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string data = jsonSerializer.Serialize(dataList);
    return data;

}



}

public class GraphData
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class GraphDataList
{
    public List<GraphData> ListOfGraphData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you load jQuery anywhere? It is a [dependency](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/index.html#getting_started).

Also, try loading Raphael before Morris. Your full dependency list should look something like this:

```
<script src="jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="morris.js"></script>
```